# Powershell output to email doesn't come with table borders

Tags: powershell

I have been using below script to send me an email with AD user end dates, after make few modifications I was able to send the email as HTML, however the email received doesn't come with borders, can someone help me please.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$date = Get-Date
$begdate = Get-Date -date $date -Format "MMM d"
$dateadd = $date.adddays(15) -as [datetime]
$enddate = Get-Date -date $dateadd -Format "MMM d" 

$expireds = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Contosa,DC=ad,DC=Contosa,DC=com" -AccountExpired | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} | Select Name, AccountExpirationdate,DistinguishedName,@{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser(Get-ADUser $_ -properties Manager).manager).Name}} | select-object Name, Manager, AccountExpirationdate, Comments | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
    if ($expireds -eq $null){
        $body = "Good morning, `n`nThere are currently no expired accounts."
        }
    else {
        $body ="Good morning, <br> <br> The following accounts have been detected as expired yet still active <br>"
        $out = $expireds | Out-String
        $style = “</style>”
        $style = $style + “BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}”
        $style = $style + “TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}”
        $style = $style + “TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }”
        $style = $style + “TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }”
        $style = $style + “</style>”
        $body += $out
        }

$body += "<br> `n`nAdditionally...`n`n"

$expiring = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Contosa,DC=ad,DC=Contosa,DC=com" -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "15" | where {$_.Enabled -eq $true}| Select Name, AccountExpirationdate,DistinguishedName,@{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser(Get-ADUser $_ -properties Manager).manager).Name}} | select-object Name, Manager, AccountExpirationdate, Comments | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style2
    if ($expiring -eq $null){
        $body += "<No accounts are expiring within next 15 days."
        }
    Else {
        $body += "<br> The following accounts were detected as expiring in next 15 days."
        $out = $expiring | Out-String
        $style2 = “</style>”
        $style2 = $style2 + “BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}”
        $style2 = $style2 + “TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}”
        $style2 = $style2 + “TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }”
        $style2 = $style2 + “TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }”
        $style2 = $style2 + “</style>”
        $body += $out
        }

$fromaddress = "AD-Enddates@contosa.com"
$toaddress = "rolex@contosa.com" 
$SMTPServer = "email.contosa.com"
$SMTPPort = 587

$subject = "Weekly Account Report for $begdate `- $enddate"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true

$message.From = $fromaddress

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)

$smtp.send($message)
```

[attached is the email how i receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5WQZ.png)

Comment: Start by changing `$style = “</style>”` to `$style = "<style>"`

Comment: In addition to Mathias's comment, `$style` and `$style2` are being used before being defined.

Comment: Thanks much for your suggestions, will modify and check

Answer (score 1):

You're using `| ConvertTo-Html -Head $style` and `| ConvertTo-Html -Head $style2` before those variables are being defined, in addition, you don't need to define the CSS two times. The other issue is what [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291669/powershell-output-to-email-doesnt-come-with-table-borders#comment124256172_70291669) pointed out, the `</style>` element at the beginning is incorrect.

I'm not sure how to do this using only `ConvertTo-Html` since there are 2 tables you would need to export, so I can show you an example of how to do it using [`Here-Strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings).

```
# First collect the Expired and Expiring users from Active Directory
# This is just an example, change it for Search-ADAccount
$expired = 0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = "Example.User$_"
        AccountExpirationdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-5)
    }
}

$expiring = 0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = "Example.User$_"
        AccountExpirationdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(15)
    }
}

# Store the CSS on a variable for future use
$style = @'
BODY{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
TABLE{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
TH{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #dddddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
TD{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
'@

# -Fragment: Generates only an HTML table.
# The HTML, HEAD, TITLE, and BODY tags are omitted.
$expiredHTML = $expired | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$expiringHTML = $expiring | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

$htmlResult = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
$style
</style>
<body>
Good morning,
<br><br>
The following accounts have been detected as expired yet still active
<br><br>
$expiredHTML
<br>
Additionally...
<br>
The following accounts were detected as expiring in next 15 days
<br><br>
$expiringHTML
</body>
</html>
"@

$htmlResult | Out-File ./test.html
Invoke-Item ./test.html
```

**Sample**

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestions, sorry im a rookie and didnt knew much about scripting.. let me make changes and test it

Comment: @user17636560 no need to be sorry, we're all learning here. besides, your question at least shows effort :)

Comment: Thanks much for taking time and helping me in resolving the issue, i can confirm that emails are being generated with table borders now, after defining $style variable first. 

much appreciated

Comment: @user17636560 happy to help, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue where the first table was always ok then the second was weird. The second table ... and forth table ... and six table ... the cells were also bordered.  Just don't apply the header to each table, just apply it once for this to not happen anymore.  I was also using outlook so no CSS.  Cheers!

```
$Header = "<style>"
$Header += "table {border-width: 1px; border-style:solid; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$Header += "th {background: #0046c3; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px; border-width: 1px; border-style:solid}"
$Header += "td {font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 20px; color: #000; border-width: 1px; border-style:solid}"
$Header += "</style>"
$htmltable_desc = "<br><br><b>The below table shows stuff:</b>"
$htmlTable = $newOwnerArray1 | Sort-Object -Property Time | Select-Object "stuff","otherStuff" | ConvertTo-Html
$htmltable_desc1 = "<br><br><b>The below table shows stuff:</b>"
$htmlTable1 = $newOwnerArray1 | Sort-Object -Property Time | Select-Object "stuff","otherStuff" | ConvertTo-Html
$body = $header + $htmltable_desc +_ $htmlTable + $htmltable_desc1 + $htmlTable1
```